# Why does Visual Studio Type a Newly Minted Array as Nullable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm writing a function with a generic type `TVal`. I wrote this line:

```
var zeroBased = new TVal[size];
```

And then in Visual Studio (VS) I used alt+enter to replace `var` with an explicit type. Here's what I got:

```
TVal[]? zeroBased = new TVal[size];
```

I was surprised to find the `?` operator, indicating that the type might be nullable. I thought that I'd be safe enough assuming the type is never null when created with `new`, and could have just done:

```
TVal[] zeroBased = new TVal[size];
```

Is there a scenario where instantiating a new array in C# can give you back null?

Note: the code seems to compile fine without the `?`, I'm just intrigued by VS's suggestion...

#### Minimal Verifiable Example

Open Visual Studio, same version as specified below, create a new project, enable nullable types as per the VS Project File Contents below, create a new class, and pop in this function:

```
public void Test<T>(int size)
{
  var tArr = new T[size];
}
```

The select the `var` and hit `alt+enter`, and choose to replace `var` with explicit type. If the behaviour is the same as the one I experienced, you'll get:

```
public void Test<T>(int size)
{
  T[]? tArr = new T[size];
}
```

#### Visual Studio Project File Contents

We're using C# 8 for this project and we've enabled Nullables:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <WarningsAsErrors>CS8600;CS8602;CS8603</WarningsAsErrors>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <Version>1.0.0.9</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Dynamic.Runtime" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

#### Visual Studio Version Info (just bits that seemed important to this Q)

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.6.1
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.6.1+30128.74
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03062

Installed Version: Community

C# Tools   3.6.0-4.20251.5+910223b64f108fcf039012e0849befb46ace6e66
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Comment: What versions are you using? (visual studio, c#, .NET, etc) Also, can you please add the  surrounding code for context? ie: if there was code we could copy/paste into LinqPad to help find the answer

Comment: I can't reproduce it, got `T[]` with mentioned code

Comment: You initialize it with a non-null value, but you could set it to null later, as far as the compiler can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio with C# 8 allows you to use nullable types according to the contexts you setup in your project.  You can find docs [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

One way to enable it is with a `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` entry in your project file.  If you have that then it'll choose to use the nullable type when you convert to explicit variable.

I'm not sure if that same behavior would be used for the other ways - pragmas for example - to enable it.  I only tried the project file method.

Answer (score 11):

#### I would like to extend an existing answer by adding some links

[C# specification proposal says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types-specification#nullable-implicitly-typed-local-variables):

> **nullable implicitly typed local variables**
>
> `var` infers an annotated type for reference types. For instance, in
>   `var s = ""`; the `var` is inferred as `string?`.

It means that `var` for reference types infers a nullable reference type. This works if `nullable context` is enabled either using project file or `#nullable` pragma.

This behavior was discussed [in this LDM](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-12-18.md#var) and implemented in this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/40755).

[This is a reason](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-12-18.md#var) for making `var` infer a nullable reference type:

> At this point we've seen a large amount of code that requires people
>   spell out the type instead of using var, because code may assign null
>   later.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to extend existing answers with my own interpretation. [MikeJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62268184/5134722) cracked this problem and got to the heart of it. It all boils down to nullability being enabled- which we had for this project (but not others, which is what threw me off!).

[Iliar Turdushev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62274371/5134722) then added some explicit references in support of the original answer. In particular, we were pointed to a [recent discussion by the C# team on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-12-18.md#var). That document, and the existing answer, quoted it saying the following:

> At this point we've seen a large amount of code that requires people spell out the type instead of using var, because code may assign null later.

I found this difficult to understand without the context. So here is the context that explains the above:

```
var current = myLinkedList.Head; // annotated not null
while (current is object)
{
    ...
    current = current.Next; // warning, Next is annotated nullable, but current is non-null
}
```

Breaking it down, let's look at that first line:

```
var current = myLinkedList.Head; // annotated not null
```

Since the `Head` property is annotated as not null, it would be perfectly OK for the compiler to interpret the var as non-nullable. However, this non-nullability would then stick with the variable forever, even if, at some point in the program, we wanted to make it null e.g. in this line:

```
 current = current.Next; // warning, Next is annotated nullable, but current is non-null
```

The C# team said, OK, we have two options here. We can either interpret `var` as nullable always, or we can interpret it as non-nullable when it's inferrible from context, and allow users to specify `var?` to explicitly state that they want a nullable type. But my reading of their document is that `var?` sort of violates the whole principle of `var`, which is convenience. If we had to stick an extra `?` onto the end of `var` every time we used it, it's probably time we just got explicit about the type and stopped using var.

Thus, the C# team conclude:

> Make var have a nullable annotated type and infer the flow type as normal.

This means that if you assign a non-nullable to a `var`, you can safely assign null to that same reference later on in the code without getting any warnings. [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121309/hans-ke%EF%AC%86ing) commented about this too. So, for example, bringing it back to the original Q, I could do:

```
public void Test<T>(int size)
{
  var tArr = new T[size];
  //Some code
  tArr = null; //This is OK, because var is treated as T[]?, not T[]
}
```

And I wouldn't get any warnings. So VS is behaving properly here- it's respecting the behaviour of the compiler to treat a `var` as nullable, as designed, *even when that var is initialised to a non-nullable value*. Meaning, and this is the key point for me and the heart of my question:

**It's up to you as the programmer to remove nullability after converting a var to an explicit type, if that's what you want.**

And that's just what I will do in this case!

Comment: "But my reading of their document is that var? sort of violates the whole principle of var, which is convenience." It seems more convenient to me that when assigning a variable using the 'new' keyword, we can use 'var' for the non-nullable variable definition (which should be the default) and 'var?' for the nullable case. Having to type out the whole name of the type is NOT convenient. I know it's done, but I disagree with making nullability the default assumption.

Comment: @OverlordZurg I just ran across this issue, being new to .net core and NRT's, and this seems like a bizarre decision to me. Nothing in c# is less convenient than having to type out a long type name instead of letting the compiler infer it for you. But then you lose the benefit of the null checking entirely. I wrote this question seeking a way around this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841528/is-there-any-way-to-have-non-nullable-type-inference-in-c

Comment: @Colm Bhandal: How do "remove nullability"?