# Non-nullable reference type: why is my object considered nullable by the compiler?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nullable-reference-types

I've a project on which I enabled the new [Nullable reference type feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types)

```xml
 <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Now let's consider this code

```cs
public class Foo  {    }

var foo = new Foo();
```

The compiler considers the `foo` variable to be nullable (`Foo?`).
Why is that? I don't understand.

Now with the Nullable reference type feature enabled the returned `Foo` object isn't supposed to be null because it is a non-nullable type.

If I wanted it to be nullable I'd specify it has a `Foo?`

So why is the compiler saying it's a nullable variable?

Thank you

## EDIT

Here is a screenshot of what I'm describing here. When you hover your mouse over the `foo` variable

[image: Hover the foo variable]

Comment: Can't reproduce it, `var foo = new Foo();` doesn't show any warnings. What is the inside `Foo` class?

Comment: Nothing is in the `Foo` class as shown in my code example it's empty. There's no warning but in VS is you hover your mouse over the `foo` variable it says it's a `Foo?`

Comment: A similar question was asked here: [Why does Visual Studio Type a Newly Minted Array as Nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267427/why-does-visual-studio-type-a-newly-minted-array-as-nullable) Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the original implementation, `foo` would have been inferred as a `Foo`.

However, people complained that this got in the way of things like:

```
string? GetThing() => ...

var result = "";
if (condition)
{
    result = GetThing();
}
```

If `result` is inferred as a `string`, then the `result = GetThing()` line causes a warning: `GetThing()` returns a `string?`, and there's a warning if you try and assign a `string?` to a `string`.

The solution was to infer `result` as a `string?`, but the compiler knows that it's currently not null (its "flow state" is "NotNull").

This means that:

```
string? GetThing() => ...

var result = "";

// No warning, as the compiler knows that result isn't null
int l1 = result.Length; 

if (condition)
{
    result = GetThing();
}

// Warning: the compiler knows 'result' might have been re-assigned
int l2 = result.Length;
```

---

For other examples of the flow state at work, see things like:

```
string? result = GetString();
if (result == null)
    throw new Exception();

// No warning: the compiler knows that result can't be null here: if it was,
// the exception above would have been thrown
int l1 = result.Length;
```

```
string? result = GetString();

// Warning: result might be null
int l1 = result.Length; 

// No warning: the compiler knows that result can't be null here: if it was,
// the line above would have thrown
int l2 = result.Length;
```

```
string result = "hello";
if (result == null)
    Console.WriteLine("NULL!");

// Warning: because we checked for null above, the compiler assumes that we
// know something that it doesn't, and so result might be null.
int l1 = result.Length;
```

Comment: Alright thanks for your answer. As you said `The solution was to infer result as a string?, but the compiler knows that it's currently not null (its "flow state" is "NotNull")` but how about me? I mean now I'm super confused because every time I hover over a variable it tells me it's a nullable and then I have to check if this is really a nullable or not... Any way to change that behavior in intellisense? Or is the only way not to use the `var` keyword?

Comment: My advice is just not to worry about it. The ability to explicitly mark locals as nullable is a bit questionable anyway: there's strictly no need, since the compiler has all of the information it needs there and then to know whether it might be null. There should be no reason you'd care if your variable was a `Foo?` instead of a `Foo`.

Comment: Well I think there're good reasons to care about it. Because if it's a nullable variable then I've to take care of checking if this variable is null or not before using it. I've a repository which for example returns a nullable object on the `GetById` method but returns a non-nullable array on the `Search` method. The array could be empty if no result matches with the search parameters but it can never be null. But now the compiler just confuses me by saying the returned object might be nullable.

Comment: Now everywhere in my code my reaction is like `Wait what?!! Is the object really nullable here? Ah no this is just the damn compiler lying to me...`

Comment: I didn't write this, I'm just repeating the explanation I saw. If you have gripes, you can take them to the csharplang gitter, but I doubt you'll get far: things are the way they are for a good reason. Also just make sure you're using an up to date VS: I remember mine explicitly telling me whether a variable can be null at a particular given point (although I'm not at a computer to check)

Comment: You're welcome to rant, but please don't direct it near me.

Comment: Sorry if you felt like it was directed to you. Thanks for the `csharplang gitter`, I'll ask about it even though I also think this won't go anywhere

Comment: Honestly, this is just plain dumb. You lose the strength of explicit nullable types if the `var` keyword just blindly makes every reference type nullable. The only solution, it seems, is to write out types explicitly and avoid the `var` keyword entirely, which quickly becomes tedious. I really wish they'd included a project flag to disable this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the specification on nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types-specification). It states that `var` infers an annotated type for reference types.

The part under the heading **nullable implicitly typed local variables** reads:

> var infers an annotated type for reference types. For instance, in var s = ""; the var is inferred as string?.

Comment: The spec appears to be plain incorrect there with regards to the actual (current) implementation. If this were correct, `var s = ""; int i = s.Length;` should produce a warning; it does not (as well it should not). It states a little further that interpolated strings are never `null`, so that would mean `var s = $""` would be different and typed as `string` -- for no obvious reason. It may be this discrepancy in implementations that's reflected in the analyzer, though.

Comment: The [later part of that spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types-specification#type-inference) seems to contradict the section quoted. - "The type inferred for local variables declared with var is informed by the null state of the initializing expression."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I actually missed the relevant bit but it does indeed explicitly contradict itself: "The null state of a `null` literal is "maybe null". The null state of a `default` literal that is being converted to a type that is known not to be a nonnullable value type is "maybe null". The null state of any other literal is "not null"." Ergo, `""` has a null state of "not null" (as of course it should) and the type inferred for `var s = ""` is `string`, the example notwithstanding.

Comment: This is an area which changed relatively recently IIRC. I believe the current implementation would treat `var` the same as `string?`, but as if the user had already done a null-check on it, so the compiler knows that it can't be null (unless you assign something else to it)

Comment: @canton7: that would be consistent with the current implementation, which allows `var foo = new Foo()` to be reassigned with `null` (which of course is not allowed for `Foo foo = new Foo()`). It's unfortunate that nobody seems to have gotten around to update the spec to at least not be contradictory... But I suppose a remark to that effect would be met with "pull request plz". :-P