# Why does async/await in C# return nullable values even when told not to?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await, nullable-reference-types

Using C#8, Visual Studio 2019 16.7.2, given the following C# code:

```cs
#nullable enable

public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(); ...

public async void Main()
{
    var theString = await GetStringAsync();
    ...
}
```

Intellisense hovering over `theString` shows a tooltip of **local variable (string?) theString**

My `GetStringAsync` method never returns a nullable string, yet the variable is inferred as being nullable.

Is this an intellisense bug? Or is there something deeper going on where `theString` can actually be null due to some way that `await` works?

Comment: Redirected to the compiler team through a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/47114). We should get an answer soon whether this is a bug, not a bug, or by-design.

Comment: This is not a behavior of vs 2019 version "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 16.6.5". in this version intellisense shows "string".

Comment: But, if you declare `theString` as `string theString` it will be `string` right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Visual Studio Type a Newly Minted Array as Nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267427/why-does-visual-studio-type-a-newly-minted-array-as-nullable)

Comment: Intellisense will also show you a message like: "'theString' is not null here.", so the information you need to use the variable correctly/safely should be readily available.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is by-design and does not have to do with the `await`.

`var` is always nullable, from [the spec](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types-specification.md#nullable-implicitly-typed-local-variables):

> `var` infers an annotated type for reference types. For instance, in `var s = "";` the `var` is inferred as `string?`.

As such, you can't explicitly specify `theString` as non-nullable when you use `var`. If you want it to be non-nullable, use `string` explicitly.

---

As to why: In short, it's to allow scenarios like this:

```csharp
#nullable enable

public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(); ...

public async void Main()
{
    var theString = await GetStringAsync();
    
    if (someCondition)
    {
        // If var inferred "string" instead of "string?" the following line would cause
        // warning CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
        theString = null;
    }
}
```

The compiler will use flow analysis to determine whether or not the variable is null at any given point. [You can read more about the decision here.](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-12-18.md#var)

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that `var` was always nullable. Makes a lot of sense, and I guess I got sent down the wrong track thinking it was somehow related to async

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same thing, with we had some non null var...

Comment: Strange. You would think that if you want to assign null lateron, you'd have to write var theString = (string?) (await ....) instead.