# Is there any way to have non-nullable type inference in c#?

Tags: c#, type-inference

I've finally upgraded a big project to .NET Core and C# 12, and was excited because I can now use nullable reference types. But I promptly discovered that variables created by type inference are nullable, which defeats the whole purpose of nullability checking, because I use type inference everywhere.

Consider an API like

`Task<List<My.Very.Long.Namespace.Chain.Item>> GetSomeDataThatIsNeverNull(int id);`

It is quite nice to write

`var data = await GetSomeDataThatIsNeverNull(123);`

and awful to write

`List<My.Very.Long.Namespace.Chain.Item> data = await GetSomeDataThatIsNeverNull(123);`

just to cause `data` to be non-nullable.

I understand the reason why it works this way (explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63582116/349974) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62274371/349974)) and it seems to have to do with assigning null later. But that seems like a very specific use case; most of the time, I want to fetch an object and use it, and never set it to null, and if I did, I'd want to be explicit about it only in that case, or make an entirely new variable for it.

So: Is there any way to create a proper non-nullable reference type without having to write out the type name?

*Update*: A commenter asked for a code sample:

```
string Foo() => "foo";
var foo = Foo();
```

`Foo()` is a method that's declared to return a `string`, not a nullable `string`, does in fact always return a non-null string, and yet the type of `foo` is inferred as `string?`:

[image]

Typing `string` isn't much worse than typing `var`, but this is definitely not true for types like `List<My.Very.Long.Namespace.Chain.Item>`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, unless you're using Reflection to inspect the variable, the compiler already knows that `data` isn't null. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqvni.png

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, that should work already

Comment: @gunr2171: That's odd. When I enter that code, my variable `a` is typed as `string?`. Could there be some project setting that I'm missing?

Comment: If I hover over `var` from my code it shows the type is a `System.String?`.

Comment: Right. That is what I don't want it to do. The whole point here is to be able to know when an object should never be null, and it seems like var basically turns that whole feature off.

Comment: Unless you'd like to propose a change to the C# spec, it's doing it [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63582116/349974).

Comment: It looks like that ship has sailed. I guess I should have been paying more attention to the proposal process.

Comment: In my experience inferred type depends on the return type of the function. If it's string then the inferred type is not nullable, if it's string? then the inferred type is nullable. In this case it would be Task<string> or Task<string?> of course. I can't remember to have ever witnessed the behaviour described here and in the linked posts.

Comment: Could you provide the actual code you have or a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Tangentially related: you could alias your types with a `using` clause, `using MyList = List<My.Stupidly.Long.Namespace.MyClass>; `

Comment: Now I see it too. I think it is simply something you shouldn't be overly concerned about. Just use var. Even if the type is considered nullable by the compiler doesn't mean it will be run like that in the end result i.e. after JIT. The nullable feature is more about expressing the intent to get a nullable or non nullable parameter in a function. If you pass null to non nullable parameter you will be warned by the compiler. In case of a return: whether the variable is T or T? you can use it just the same and I doubt, that at runtime, it will be a Nullable<T> instance.

Comment: The code will work fine, as it always has, but you lose the benefit of the flow analysis that is the whole point of nullable reference types. So

Comment: Why the close votes? I get that the answer to my question is "no, it's not possible", but does that make it a bad question?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some comments on your question, I do think your question is valid. To paraphrase, I believe you want this code to generate a compilation warning:

```
var foo = "hi";
foo = null;
```

The same way that this code generates a compilation warning:

```
string foo = "hi";
foo = null;
```

I must admit, I am not certain if there is a way - I am not aware of one. However, while I am of the same mind as yours that it may be handy to have control over this default (I too support stricter rather than looser, for several reasons, reasoning seems out of scope here), I would like to point out that I don't believe this "turns that whole feature off", as you say. The real question is, what do you eventually *do* with `foo`, after you do (or don't) assign `null` into it? If you try to dereference it - the compiler will behave as expected. This will raise a warning, as expected:

```
var foo = "hi";
foo = null;
var bar = foo.Length; // <-- CS8602
```

This will not, as expected:

```
var foo = "hi";
var bar = foo.Length; // No problem
```

If you try to return the variable from a method, same thing. This will raise a warning, as expected:

```
string MyMethod() {
  var foo = "hi";
  foo = null;
  return foo; // <-- CS8603
}
```

This will not, as expected:

```
string MyMethod() {
  var foo = "hi";
  return foo; // No problem
}
```

And of course, a big use-case is when your variable is not a hard-coded value but a value returned from some other API surface, and that still behaves as expected. This will raise a warning, as expected:

```
string MyMethod1() {
  var foo = MyMethod2();
  return foo; // <-- CS8603
}

string? MyMethod2() { // Nullable return type
  return "hi";
}
```

This will not, as expected:

```
string MyMethod1() {
  var foo = MyMethod2();
  return foo; // No problem
}

string MyMethod2() { // Non-nullable return type
  return "hi";
}
```

> Note: In case these examples may behave differently in different compilation targets and language versions, I'll just add that my code was compiled using .Net 7.0 and C# 11.

So it looks like static analysis goes much further than what the IDE shows us when hovering over the variable. I actually don't know why Visual Studio (at least as of version 17.8.5 on my end) can't show us the same thing that the compiler already seems to know - I suppose that would be much clearer, and would pretty much remove the need for (most of) this discussion . Either way, perhaps the correct phrasing is not "`var` is always nullable" as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63582116/198797), but rather "`var` is always inferable as nullable, depending on the rest of your code". The compiler does allow assigning `null` into the variable, but also stays aware whether you do or don't, and will behave accordingly. For me, this satisfies a strong subset of the NRT promise.

If you find something that doesn't work as you expect (granted, other than the sheer assignability of `null` into the variable) please do leave a comment on my answer, as I'm sure the community would like to be aware.