# Why are interface methods returning non-nullable reference types being treated as nullable vars?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, nullable-reference-types, c#-10.0

I'm new to C#10 and the default enabled [nullable NRT functionality](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/embracing-nullable-reference-types/). In the following simple example I'm curious why VS2022 tells me (via tooltip) that `o` is `object?` when the interface definition explicitly states it is `object`.

Is this standard behavior and what's the reason for it? Is it because the compiler has no way of telling that the interface implementation is null-safe so has to assume the worst?

Further, `s` is also nullable (`string?`) but no warnings or errors are given when I use these nullable types. The compiler confidently informs me that "o is not null here" when I call `o.ToString`.

I can't tell at this stage if NRTs marks a paradigm shift to how we write modern C# or is "just another language tweak?" What's going on here? I want to 'embrace' it but am struggling with the full understanding of another change to the language.

```
public interface ITest
{
    Object GetObject();
}

public class Tester
{
    public void Test(ITest i)
    {
        var o = i.GetObject(); //object?
        var s = o.ToString(); //string?
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it adds the `?`, but the compiler seems to know it's not null https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4nIs.png

Comment: How do you know it's inferred as `object?` and `string?` instead of `object` and `string` ?

Comment: "From tooltips" It might be an IDE artifact instead of a compiler artifact. What IDE are you using?

Comment: Another hint: does your code compile if you say `object o = i.GetObject();` and `string s = o.ToString();`? Or does it only compile with `object?` and `string?` ?

Comment: And one final hint: `string?` and `string` are both `System.String`. There is no separate type for nullable reference types

Comment: @MattThomas VS2022 (current AFAIK). Could this really be a bug in the IDE?

Comment: @Mr.Boy no, it is not a bug, it was planned this way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267427/why-does-visual-studio-type-a-newly-minted-array-as-nullable

Answer (score 0):

Although an interface implementation written in C# might not be able to return null, there is no requirement that interface implementations be written only in C#.  If an interface is implemented by code written in another language, nothing would prevent that code from returning null.

A similar issue arises, incidentally, with the `TryGetValue` method of `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`.  If one has a structure with member m whose constructor invokes:

```
SomeIDictionary.TryGetValue(someKey, ref m);
```

the C# compiler will blindly assume that the interface method will not return without storing a value into `m` (e.g. because the key is not found).  This may have the surprising effect of causing a statement like:

```
myStruct = new myStructType(someParameters);
```

to leave `myStruct.m` holding whatever value it held beforehand.

Comment: The key point is that while C# makes a distinction between nullable and non-nullable object types, the mechanisms used to allow cross-language interoperability make no such distinctions.  If someone implements an interface function in a language which doesn't have non-nullable reference types, and does so in a way that never returns null, the fact that their language doesn't have non-nullable reference types wouldn't matter.  There is no way, however, that C# could allow that while ensuring that code written in other languages won't ever return null.

Comment: My point about `out` vs `ref` parameters is that they illustrate a situation where C# blindly expected that interface implementations would obey C# rules, and such expectation yielded rather surprising consequences.  Allowing code to blindly treat a "nun-nullable" reference returned from an interface method as something that will never be null could likewise have surprising consequences if an implementation written in some other language does something unusual.

Comment: The C# compiler is not unjustified in making the assumption for `.TryGetValue`, if only for the simple reason that the interface's contract is explicitly documented as requiring that the `out` parameter be set in a particular way depending on whether the key is found. An implementation that doesn't isn't just being unusual, it's simply wrong. You might have a case for other methods using `out` parameters, if they forget to document this and assume it must be true because C# enforces it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: It's not uncommon for a private class to implement just enough aspects of a interface to meet the needs of a particular consumer to which it will be passed.  If `TryGetValue` were declared as accepting a `ref` parameter, and a struct constructor were to pass an as-yet-uninitialized field, C# would set it to its default value before the call, rendering moot the question of whether `TryGetValue` would do likewise.  It would, however, make the function rather painful to use from C# in many other contexts.  The fact that `out` can silently affect semantics, rather than merely...

Comment: ...controlling what constructs are accepted, strikes me as a surprising aspect of behavior that would catch many people by surprise.  What's surprising isn't the fact that the passed variable won't be altered if the interface method doesn't alter it, but rather the fact that C# omits the default initialization of a struct member that it expects to be written by a method.

Comment: Ah, I didn't glean from your answer that *that* was the behavior you were referring to -- going into the method rather than out of it. Maybe specifically mentioning `IDictionary.TryGetValue` was a bit of a red herring there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: That's the only example I could think of where a C#-only language feature could yield unexpected behavior when interacting with code written in other languages.  I suspect many programmers would expect that "out" in an interface definition to mean "Allow a function to be passed an object that isn't definitely assigned, but treat it as definitely assigned after the function returns", but not that the compiler can make assumptions based upon that.  If an interface method that returns non-nullable were treated as non-nullable for purposes of silencing diagnostics...

Comment: @JeroenMostert: ...but could nonetheless be null, that might interfere with the ability of client code written in C# to conveniently test whether the outside method had actually returned a non-null value, since a comparison between a non-nullable reference and null would from a language perspective not be meaningful run-time test.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) says the type is `object` not `object?`

[image: Screenshot of source code in Rider IDE]

Also, Rider will refactor the `var` into `object`:

[image: Context menu in Rider]

[image: Screenshot of Rider refactoring the var into object]

Note: the code will compile even if I manually say `object?`:

[image: Screenshot after manually specifying nullable object]

[image: Successful build]

Keep in mind nullable reference types are magic sugar sprinkled on top of the type system. Under the hood there's no difference between `object` and `object?`; both refer to `System.Object`. That magical sugar layer is able to deduce that my `object?` is not null (because its value came from an interface that promises never to return null).

---

Being pedantic: there's no difference in the type system between a nullable *reference* type and the same non-nullable *reference* type. But there *is* a difference between nullable and non-nullable *value* types. To be more precise: `double` is the `System.Double` struct, but `double?` is the `System.Nullable<System.Double>` struct. MS crammed more magic into the language and compiler to support this bifurcation between reference and value types. This would be a great opportunity to start writing glowing things about the type systems in TypeScript or Rust or any of a dozen other languages.