# Why does tuple deconstruction return nullable types in C#?

Tags: c#, tuples, type-inference, deconstructor

Consider the following C# code:

```
var info = ("A", "B");
if (info is var (a, b))
{
    Console.WriteLine("X = {0}", a);
}
```

For some reason, the type of the `a` variable is inferred as optional (`string?`), while neither the whole tuple nor its elements can be nullable. At the same time, Visual Studio hints that `a` cannot be null within the condition's block:

[image: Inference result]

Is there any particular reason why type inference should work like this here?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076484/c-sharp-10-is-there-a-way-to-make-var-define-the-variable-as-non-nullable and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267427/why-does-visual-studio-type-a-newly-minted-array-as-nullable