# C# Nullable issues with implicitly-typed local variables

Tags: c#, nullable

I already know from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267427/why-does-visual-studio-type-a-newly-minted-array-as-nullable) that implicitly declared reference types are nullable in .NET 7 even when `Nullable` set to "Enabled",   I even know why.

*I am not asking why*.  I am asking about a workaround.

In the comments, @shingo pointed out a workaround to my simple example so here I will list the issue that brought me here:  The result of a LINQ query.  The variable `nonEmpty` below is actually nullable

```
var nonEmpty = myList.Where(s => s.Length > 0).ToList();
nonEmpty = null;  // again valid when it should not be
```

To make it non-nullable, I must explicitly declare the type.

```
List<string> nonEmpty = myList.Where(s => s.Length > 0).ToList();
nonEmpty = null;  // compiler warning/error as desired.
```

That's not an issue with short-named types like `List<string>`.  But when the names are really long as they are in my code, it is.

So my question is:

Is there any sort of short-hand method I can use that lets me avoid having to declare the type here?  Or even a language proposal for such a trick in the future?

I actually tried all of the 3 following declarations, none of which worked.   Only the 3rd even compiles.

```
var! nonEmpty = myList.Where(s => s.Length > 0).ToList();
var nonEmpty! = myList.Where(s => s.Length > 0).ToList();
var nonEmpty = myList.Where(s => s.Length > 0).ToList()!
```

Comment: Something's wrong. `new List<string>()` does not return a nullable type. Are you certain nullable reference types are enabled, and that `myList` is flagged as nullable?

Comment: Yes I am.  The item I linked to describes that it was apparently a deliberate decision by the C# language designers.  I even went so far as to create a brand new test project with nullable enabled and added that line saw the same effect  If you do it and put that line down and hover your mouse over the list variable.  You will see it listed by Intellisense as nullable.   I couldn't believe it either.

Comment: `List<string> myList = new();`

Comment: Whoever closed this please actually try to read what was asked before  knee-jerk closing it.  The linked question answers *why* the language is this way.  I am not asking that.  I am asking  if there is a work-around or even a proposal for one in the future.  That does not have an answer in the linked question and besides the linked question is from 3 language version sago.

Comment: @shingo - Thank you.  I cannot believe I forgot about implicit new.   At first I thought tat was the answer to my question. But then I forgot that does not save my implicitly defined variables that result from, say a LINQ ToList call.  If I said `var myVals = myStrings.ToList()` then `myVals` would again be nullable.  And the only way to fix it is to explicitly declare the type, defeating the purpose nullable with var

Comment: Is there an *actual problem* to solve here, though? The simple solution to reassigning the variable would be "don't do that, then". Despite the `var` being implicitly nullable, static analysis will treat it as not null for the rest of the method, so nullability analysis is not affected unless you reassign the variable to `null` -- and if you do, it will warn again. The only thing you're currently not getting is an explicit warning if you do assign `null`, and while that might be seen as a shortcoming, I'd argue the real problem is reassigning the local at all, the value is secondary.

Comment: Related to the above: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/188 .

Comment: @JeroenMostert Unfortunately, there is an actual problem to solve here.  In an ideal world, I would write the code once, it would be perfect and nobody would ever need to work on it again.  Unfortunately many people work on this codebase.  Having a non-nullable type will make the compiler catch it when they come along a year later and make some change that tries to assign null to variable that was intended never to be that way.  It's the whole reason we have nullable references in the first place:  To have the compiler catch things when we accidentally slip up.

Comment: I think you're missing my point: if someone does `nonEmpty = null`, they *will* get warnings if an attempt is subsequently made to use `nonEmpty` in a way that requires it not to be `null`. The assignment won't warn, but the assignment isn't the thing causing trouble -- that would be accessing a possibly `null` reference, which the analysis will still warn about. Or to put it philosophically, if a `null` is assigned that is never read, does it make a sound? Not really.

Comment: I take your point now.  I might  have too many years of C++ baked into my head to fully grok this.  I keep expecting  the compiler will (or even should) always act on nullability with respect to the type *as declared*.  But apparently it is even more dynamic than that.  For me, even properly understanding the behavior of attributes like  `[MaybeNullWhen]` attribute was a big step.

Comment: The implementation of nullability analysis and NRTs is indeed subtle -- deliberately so to ensure that existing code could get value out of it even with minimal adoption, and opt-in gradually. A simple fixed type system where a variable may never hold a `null` reference was rejected early on as something that would never get traction as it would be too costly to adapt existing code. The end result is a bit hard to understand and use from a semantics perspective, but does do "the right thing" for the most part, which is what gives it its value.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer but more of a workaround, and it will only be useful if you have multiple instances of your non-nullable long-named types - aliasing your type with a using directive, like this:

```
using strList = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;
```

Then you can use `strList` in your code as an alias to `List<string>`.
If you want to use this alias in more than one file in your project, you can use the [global modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier) for your using directive and then use that alias throughout the project (requires c# 10 or higher):

```
global using strList = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;
```

See attached image as a demo:

[image]